# Running Two Intel x5355 CPU with different spec numbers on same motherboard

Tags: central-processing-unit, intel

I have S5000PAL motherboard with latest bios and x5355 with SLAEG spec installed. I was wondering if I would put the in x5355 with SL9YM spec into second processor socket would it work? Both processors are the same but differ in the spec id.

[Here is link](http://ark.intel.com/products/28035) to x5355 processor on intel website.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It *should* work perfectly. Try it.